# C++ MIDI not working after deploy to window shop

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, midi

```
include <windows.h>
include <mmsystem.h>
int flag;
flag = midiOutOpen(&device, midiport, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);
flag = midiOutShortMsg(device, message.word);
```

These code work when I am developing
But after deploy to Window Shop, there is no sound

When deploy to window shop, I have checked "Background Media Playback" under Capabilities

The documentation I can find is UWP/CSharp, But I want to write C++

Comment: Run the [WACK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/app-certification-kit/) to find out whether you are using any APIs you shouldn't be using.

Comment: Value of `midiport`? Do you output MIDI events to the "Microsoft GS Wavetable Synthesizer"? Or is it an external MIDI port?